# DjangoCMS: Application Integration and using CMS content on non-cms (app) pages?

Tags: django, django-cms

I am using DjangoCMS for a website, and I am trying to add a registration app . Putting it in all works well, at the moment hard-coded into the urls conf, BUT, I would like to use the CMS to set the content on some of pages in the registration flow..

e.g. on the few pages the registration app uses in its flow, like "register", "activate", "activation expired", etc I would like to use CMS content for the relatively static texts, teasers, etc...  using text and other plugins, etc.

(I tried to setup pages in django-cms that mirror the same page structure as the registration pages (e.g. as my registration page is under /account/register I created a *account* page with a child-page register .. and added the template for the registration form to the CMS templates...). This works with some CMSs, but not with djano-cms... :-(.. the moment django-cms takes over the views from the registration app don't get involved anymore, and so forms don't work, etc... )

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i remember, you can use a [show_placeholder](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py#L368) tag to display info from any placeholder of any page. So put your registration urls **before** the ones of django-cms and put in your page some tags referring to your special CMS page (that page should now show up in menu, surely).

Comment: That seems to almost work. Thanks for your suggestion!
Though the rendering does not work if the url for my page is the same as the one for the "dummy" django-cms page, no matter if my own registration urls are before or after the django-cms ones. The moment the same url exists for this page in django-cms the pages don't seem to render correctly, and the contect injected by my own view is not available.

Solution seems to be to have a seperate page, that is not part of navigation, and then access the content of a specific placeholder using {show_placehoder ....}

A bit dirty but works for now

Comment: I don't remember well how do cms urls work, haven't use it for some time. Thanks for your correction!

Comment: Hmm.. sorry about the correction... I tried it on a different machine and it worked, when the urls are the same for the app's page and the "dummy" page in the CMS... I then restarted the server on my machine at home, and it worked too.. must have been some cacheing issue... so you were correct... thank you